# Cookies and postback from list item select

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am populating some labels on page 2 of my website with data from pg1 using cookies.

On pg2  i also have 2 listboxes where I add item from one to the other using a button which updates the label values.

My problem is that changing list item selection resets my label value to those from the cookies

Autopostback is enabled as I want an image to display when I select listitem

Is there a way around this possibly using `isPostBack` ??

Comment: Use session or database.

Comment: Using `isPostBack` you could populate from the cookie when `isPostBack` is false.

Comment: Im having trouble using isPostback aswell. thanks for the suggestion anyway. ill use different labels for now and keep the cookie labels constant